# THREE.GLTFLoader: Unknown extension "KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness

Tags: three.js, gltf

We have an application that exports .glb files and when I try to load them in three.js using [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader) the model shows no textures and I get this warning `THREE.GLTFLoader: Unknown extension "KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness"`. The model and textures load fine in https://github.khronos.org/glTF-Sample-Viewer-Release/ so the file is ok.

The extension seems to be deprecated from three.js (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/24950) and the suggestion is to convert the .glb file using gltf-extensions or gltf.report and save the new .glb file - this isn't very practical in my case, is it possible to tweak something to display the model with textures in three.js?

The code is standard enough:

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(uri, function loaded(gltf) {
    const model = gltf.scene;
 
    const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
    model.traverse((o) => {
        if (o.isMesh) {
            // not sure if it's relevant but if I don't .clone()
            // it removes the child and traverse crashes
            let mesh = o.clone();

            // const nextMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial();
            // THREE.MeshStandardMaterial.prototype.copy.call(mesh.material, nextMaterial);
            // mesh.material = nextMaterial;

            // mesh.material.metalness = 0;

            scene.add(mesh);
        }
    });
```

I have tried:

- [Replacing the materials after the model loads](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-use-gltf-extension/32754/5)
- [Point lighting](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/blender-exported-glb-model-not-loading-with-texture/17397/8)
- [Setting metalness to 0](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/blender-exported-glb-model-not-loading-with-texture/17397/8)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Newer versions of three.js do not include spec/gloss PBR materials, which this model requires. So there's no quick workaround here, the model must be converted to metal/rough PBR materials. That's potentially slow (textures must be rewritten) so I'd do it offline if you can.

**Option 1: UI conversion**

Load the model into https://gltf.report/, accept the prompt to convert the material, and then export the result to a new file.

**Option 2: Offline command-line conversion**

```bash
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli

gltf-transform metalrough input.glb output.glb
```

**Option 3: Runtime conversion with JavaScript**

If you *need* to do it at runtime, then:

```js
import { WebIO } from '@gltf-transform/core';
import { KHRONOS_EXTENSIONS } from '@gltf-transform/extensions';
import { metalRough } from '@gltf-transform/functions';

// Load model in glTF Transform.
const io = new WebIO().registerExtensions(KHRONOS_EXTENSIONS);
const document = await io.read('path/to/model.glb');

// Convert materials.
await document.transform(metalRough());

// Write back to GLB.
const glb = await io.writeBinary(document);

// Load model in three.js.
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.parse(glb.buffer, '', (gltf) => {
  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: That works! Like you said it is a little slow so I'll take your advice and come up with some batch job to convert the glb files offline. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks a ton. This really helped me as I had to scratch my head for 2 full days.!! Thanks again on Don McCurdy

Answer (score 0):

It helped for me to set my `@react-three/drei` version in the `package-lock.json` to:

```json
"node_modules/@react-three/drei": {
      "version": "9.32.4"
```

A higher verion (9.66.0) caused the error for me. To install an exact version, create a `.npmrc` file in your root directory and add `save-exact=true` inside the file.