# metal model reflection with aframe 1.4.2

Tags: aframe

I have a application with aframe 1.2.0 and my plan is updating to 1.4.2. However I have an issue with metal glb model. Models don't look like metal with aframe 1.4.2

If you check the following links you can see the difference

aframe 1.2.0
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/metal-with-120

aframe 1.3.0
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/metal-with-130

aframe 1.4.2
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/metal-with-142

Did I miss something with 1.4.2?
How can I fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I looked at the console errors of the apps and the only difference is an 'THREE.GLTFLoader: Unknown extension "KHR_materials_pbrSpecularGlossiness"' error from using a newer version of three.js that i think the response here will steer you in the right direction about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886578/three-gltfloader-unknown-extension-khr-materials-pbrspecularglossiness